# How to create a life line on React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-animatable

I'm trying to create a lifeline animation on React Native, I've looked into some animation libraries but didn't find, any idea on how to do it?

Comment: Some people already made this animation with JavaScript. You can draw an animated lifeline in canvas element, is it work for you? Do you want to control it or just animation?

Comment: Just an animation as the app reads the heart rate, I'm kind of new to React and JS, could you point me to the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend trying lottie for this. Check out these resources to see how to do it.
Animation: https://lottiefiles.com/1459-heart-rate
Lottie for react native: https://github.com/lottie-react-native/lottie-react-native